# Open menu in same page while clicking icon in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

[image]

In the LinkedIn App While I click the `"in"` icon it will open a menu and show the LinkedIn Today & Recent updates. Like these it is Possible in `Jquery Mobile`.

Can any one help me how to do this in `Jquery Mobile` .
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Script :

```
<script>
    $('#viewMeButton').click(function() {
    $('#viewMe').toggle(); 
    });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
 <a href="#" id="viewMeButton">

    <div id="viewMe">       
        <div class="ui-grid-c">
          <div class="ui-block-a">
          <img src="your path" /> or 
           <span>Name 1</span>      
        </div>
            <div class="ui-block-a">
             <img src="your path" /> or 
             <span>Name 2</span>        
        </div>              
          </div>
    </div>
```